# JSON Parse an element inside an element in Python

Tags: python, json, parsing, web-scraping

I have a JSON text grabbed from an API of a website:

```
{"result":"true","product":{"made":{"Taiwan":"Taipei","HongKong":"KongStore","Area":"Asia"}}}
```

I want to capture "Taiwan" and "Taipei" but always fail.

Here is my code:

```
import json
weather = urllib2.urlopen('url')
wjson = weather.read()
wjdata = json.loads(wjson)
print wjdata['product']['made'][0]['Taiwan']
```

I always get the following error:
Keyword 0 error

Whats the correct way to parse that json?

Comment: `wjdata['product']['made']['Taiwan']`?

Comment: @Rakesh I get the following error: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Errors are pointless without context, please post full error message and print exact json that you receive.

Comment: actually he is not receiving json he is receiving string of dictionary. @xiholac761 please check my post

Answer (score 1):

You are indexing an array where there are none.
The JSON is the following:

```
{ 
    "result":"true",
    "product": {
        "made": {
            "Taiwan":"Taipei",
            "HongKong":"KongStore",
            "Area":"Asia"
        }
    }
}
```

And the above contains no arrays.

You are assuming the JSON structure to be something like this:

```
{ 
    "result":"true",
    "product": {
        "made": [
            {"Taiwan":"Taipei"},
            {"HongKong":"KongStore"},
            {"Area":"Asia"}

        ]            
    }
}
```

From a brief look at the doc pages for the json package, I found this conversion table: [Conversion table using json.loads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json-to-py-table)

It tells us that a JSON object translates to a dict. And a dict has a method called keys, which returns a list of the keys.

I suggest you try something like this:

```
#... omitted code
objectKeys = wjdata['product']['made'].keys()

# You should now have a list of the keys stored in objectKeys.
for key in objectKeys:
    print key
    if key == 'Taiwan':
        print 'Eureka'
```

I haven't tested the above code, but I think you get the gist here :)

Comment: You're right, there are no arrays. Is it possible to parse "Taipei" from that json data and print it?

Answer (score 0):

wjdata['product']['made']['Taiwan']  works

Comment: Sadly it results in an error: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Are you trying to load a dynamic data(with multiple keys) or are you trying to get just key **Taiwan**

Comment: Just the key Taiwan.